# Sorting items in List with JSF

Tags: jsf, sorting

I have a very simple jsf app. I want to sort the rows in the List.xhtml. I understand these rows come from #{friendsController.items}.
How can I sort this items in a specific way? I dont want to sort them by a specific column, I want to sort them "by hand". With a set of rules I am working on. That means I want to take the row "X" and put it in first place, then "Y" in second place....
Thanks in advance for all the help.

PD: Sorry for my english, it's my second language.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no built-in JSF solution for this problem (there are drag and drop components in RichFaces and PrimeFaces but those don't work for your case). As a last resource, there is a jQuery plugin to handle this and a good tutorial (with a good example):

- [Table Drag and Drop JQuery plugin](http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/)

EDIT (based in comment):

For your case, you just need to sort your list after filling it with the items. A code sample for this case:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean {
    //attributes...
    private List<Element> myList;

    public MyBean() {
        myList = getMyListValues(); //just to get the idea
        Comparator<Element> comparator = new Comparator<Element>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Element e1, Element e2) {
                //A basic logic for a comparator, assuming there is an Id attribute
                //in Element class. Also, make sure to test for null values (just in case...)
                return (e1.getId() > e2.getId()) ? 1 : (e1.getId() < e2.getId()) -1 : 0;
            }
        };
        Collections.sort(myList, comparator);
    }

    //getters and setters for the attributes...
}
```

After sorting your list, you can display it by using `<h:dataTable>` and it will be sorted.

NOTE: Don't sort your list in the `getMyList()` method, remember that JSF framework do 1 or more calls to getters and setters, so these methods shouldn't have a heavy logic inside them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Luiggi. I'm not sure if I explained myself, I want to sort the items before showing them. The sorting would happen in the controller, I understand the solutions you were talking about are for the user to sort them.